# Работа с базами данных в приложениях Windows 8

Tags: c#, база-данных, windows-8, microsoft-store

Изучаю разработку приложений для магазина Windows. Остановился на базах данных. С чего лучше начать? Какие сервера настраивать и где. Как получать данные  обрабатывать их?

Comment: Вы для начала опишите, что хранить нужно. Есть серверный бэкенд, есть базы данных прямо на устройстве.

Comment: Нужно и то и другое. Хранить придётся данные пользователей, различные записи, рейтинги. Думаю для начало лучше изучить серверный бэкенд.